# Inheriting an interface that is derived from another interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

Below code is of an EmployeeRepository class which derives from IEmployeeRepository.

```
 public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByGender(string Gender)
    {
        return Context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Gender == Gender).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartment(string Dept)
    {
        return Context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Dept == Dept).ToList();
    }  
}
```

IEmployeeRepository class is as follows;

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IGenericRepository<Employee>
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByGender(string Gender);
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartment(string Dept);
}
```

When I build this, I get the below error as well as some similar ones;

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0535  'EmployeeRepository' does not implement interface member 'IGenericRepository.Delete(Employee)'    RepositoryUsingEFinMVC

It compiles without an error when I change the first code block to;

```
   public class EmployeeRepository : GenericRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository(IUnitOfWork<EmployeeDBContext> unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    public EmployeeRepository(EmployeeDBContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByGender(string Gender)
    {
        return Context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Gender == Gender).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByDepartment(string Dept)
    {
        return Context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Dept == Dept).ToList();
    }

   
}
```

}

Generic Repository implements all methods and properties of IGenericRepository and it is as follows;

```
  public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : class
{
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;
    private string _errorMessage = string.Empty;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork<EmployeeDBContext> unitOfWork)
        : this(unitOfWork.Context)
    {
    }

    public GenericRepository(EmployeeDBContext context)
    {
        _isDisposed = false;
        Context = context;
    }

    public EmployeeDBContext Context { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return Entities; }
    }

    protected virtual IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get { return _entities ?? (_entities = Context.Set<T>()); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
            Context.Dispose();
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Entities.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T GetById(object id)
    {
        return Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            Entities.Add(entity);

            if (Context == null || _isDisposed)
                Context = new EmployeeDBContext();

            //Context.SaveChanges(); commented out call to SaveChanges as Context save changes will be 
            //called with Unit of work
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    _errorMessage += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;
            throw new Exception(_errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public void BulkInsert(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entities == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entities");
            }
            Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            Context.Set<T>().AddRange(entities);
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {

            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    _errorMessage += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName,
                                         validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            throw new Exception(_errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            if (Context == null || _isDisposed)
                Context = new EmployeeDBContext();

            SetEntryModified(entity);
            //Context.SaveChanges(); commented out call to SaveChanges as Context save changes will be called with Unit of work
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    _errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);

            throw new Exception(_errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            if (Context == null || _isDisposed)
                Context = new EmployeeDBContext();

            Entities.Remove(entity);
            //Context.SaveChanges(); commented out call to SaveChanges as Context save changes will be called with Unit of work
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    _errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            throw new Exception(_errorMessage, dbEx);
        }
    }

    public virtual void SetEntryModified(T entity)
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

So my questions are; 1) Why I get error in the first version? 2) Although I do not implement the methods and properties of IGenericRepository but only derive from GenericRepository which is derived from IGenericRepository, I do not get any error. Why? 3) And what is the function of the below constructors used in EmployeeRepository.

```
public EmployeeRepository(IUnitOfWork<EmployeeDBContext> unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    public EmployeeRepository(EmployeeDBContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You haven't shown `IGenericRepository<T>`, but presumably it defines a Delete method. Your `EmployeeRepository` doesn't define a Delete method. Presumably `GenericRepository<T>` *does* define a Delete method. So by inheriting from `GenericRepository<T>`, you inherit that Delete method which is required by `IGenericRepository<T>`

Comment: Think of base interfaces for interfaces as "you also have to implement these", not "these are already provided"

Comment: Well, your `IGenericRepository` defines a `Delete`-method. Your `EmployeeRepository` does not implement that member. Simply said. In your second case you derive from a class that **does** implement the `Delete`-method.